Azure Static Web App Not Deploying Blazor WASM Net 8
I am publishing my .NET 8 Blazor web app via Visual Studio 2022 publish tool.  The output states that it was successful however I still see the default Azure page for my URL.  The Azure web panel states it's waiting for deployment.
Visual Studio Output:

Azure:


I didn't realize that Blazor Web App project is not a WASM project.  I needed to add a Stand Alone WASM project in order to deploy to Static Web Sites.
